# Undefined but in array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

[image]

but when I run it, I get

[image]

[image]

and I can see the array with the postId in the state but it is returning an undefined value.

Edit: I am trying to get the array from the state object with the postId key, but instead it is returning undefined. How do I return the array with the postId key.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: `action.postId` return an object man :((, it's not a key as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action.postId` returns an *object*, not a string:

```
console.log(action.postId)
> { postId: 'BAcyDyQwcXX' }
```

As-is, you either need to use `action.postId.postId` to get the key, or unwrap `action.postId` so it contains the string, not object.

```
console.log(state[action.postId.postId]);
> Array(4)

action.postId = 'BAcyDyQwcXX';
console.log(state[action.postId]);
> Array(4)
```